# Customizing the Time-Picker in C#/UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, visual-studio-2017

Ok, I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find someone who has answered this question. I want to customize the timepicker control in UWP, and by customize I mean I don't want it to be a clock.

I need a GUI that allows the user to scroll through a looping menu, much like the timepicker does, but I couldn't figure out a way to change the timepicker control so that it will show other values besides Hour/Minute/AM-PM. I also tried to use a combobox with a carousel panel and items inside it, but it did not render the effect that I am looking for. I would really appreciate it if somebody could A.) Tell me if there is a way I can change the timepicker, or B.) Point me in the direction of a control that would render that scrolling/looping effect that I am looking for. I don't need anybody to do my work for me, just a small push in the right direction.

To be clear I want the menu to have the same effect as the Windows Alarm Setter, also portrayed by the Alarm and Time setter on iPhones if that helps with a visual.

Comment: It seems the Windows Alarm Setter use the `TimePicker` and set the 24HourClock to the ClockIdentifier propertyt. So do you want to remove the AM-PM?

Comment: No Sorry, I do not wish to use the clock at all. I just like the format for that UWP control and cannot figure out how to use it outside of the time picker and date picker. I want to be able to have 4 buttons that allow you to scroll to pick values for a coordinate system. I like the way that the clock has a flyout type menu with a looping scroll, and I want to use that for Degrees|Minutes|Seconds|Hundreths in a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a basic handmade control that has 4 listview for example.
Here a quick example :

```
<Button Content="Set localisation" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout Opened="Flyout_Opened">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid MaxHeight="150" MinWidth="100">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Degrees,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedDegrees,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid MaxHeight="150" MinWidth="100">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Minutes,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedMinutes,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid MaxHeight="150" MinWidth="100">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Seconds,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedSeconds,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid MaxHeight="150" MinWidth="100">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Hundredth,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedHundredth,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

With this C# code :

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Degrees = new ObservableCollection<int>
{
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
};
private int selectedDegrees = 0;
public int SelectedDegrees
{
    get { return selectedDegrees; }
    set { selectedDegrees = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProportyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedDegrees))); }
}


public ObservableCollection<int> Minutes = new ObservableCollection<int>
{
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
};
private int selectedMinutes = 0;
public int SelectedMinutes
{
    get { return selectedMinutes; }
    set { selectedMinutes = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedMinutes))); }
}


public ObservableCollection<int> Seconds = new ObservableCollection<int>
{
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
};

private int selectedSeconds = 0;
public int SelectedSeconds
{
    get { return selectedSeconds; }
    set { selectedSeconds = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedSeconds))); }
}
public ObservableCollection<int> Hundredth = new ObservableCollection<int>
{
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
};
private int selectedHundredth = 0;
public int SelectedHundredth
{
    get { return selectedHundredth; }
    set { selectedHundredth = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedHundredth))); }
}
private async void Flyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    SelectedDegrees = 5;
    SelectedMinutes = 4;
    SelectedSeconds = 3;
    SelectedHundredth = 1;
}
```

Here is the look it gives : 
[image: Geo picker]

### Carousel

At the time of writting those line, there isn't any looping/carousel in listview. But there is one in Combobox, I would then suggest to use a combobox instead of a ListView Control.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Degrees,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedDegrees,Mode=TwoWay}" IsDropDownOpen="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <CarouselPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```